# How to limit the size of Azure Table Storage for logs?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-storage

Is it possible to limit the size of an Azure Table Storage table? I'm using it for storing logs. Also how can I do something like, when the limit is reached, the old entries are deleted to make space for the new ones? Something like capped collections for MongoDB or Round-robin databases?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat remarkably: no, there's no way (currently) to do this that I'm aware of.

We had the same situation, and we now use the Cerebrata Diagnostics Manager (http://cerebrata.com/Products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/) to purge them periodically.

It is also possible to explicitly drop the WAD* tables, but you may see issues if you have an instance still running when you do this. From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/3329834a-ddae-4180-b787-ceb7aee16e83:

> @Sam --> I would be careful about deleting the table. Deleting the
>   WAD* table is a viable option if you don't have too much data in it.
>   What happens when you delete a table is that it is not deleted at that
>   very moment however it is marked for deletion and some background
>   process actually deletes that table. If you (or the diagnostics
>   process) try to create the same table you would get an error that
>   "Table is being deleted".

You can also use Visual Studio to purge logs from a given time: the above link includes a way to do that. I have a feeling that a Powershell script could also be written to do this.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the quick reply! I appreciate it. Advanced happy new year! :-)